# Route [events.store] not defined

Tags: php, html, laravel, fullcalendar

Every time it keeps on saying that the Route events.store is defined but in fact it is ,I don't know where I'm going wrong with my code .

This is is my calendar.blade.php class:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('calendar.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Full Calendar</title>

    {!!Html::style('vendor2/seguce92/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css')!!}
    {{Html::style('css/app.css')}}


</head>

<div class='container'></div>

{{ Form::open(['route' => 'events.store', 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form']) }}
```

And this is my web.php:

```
 Route::get('/calendar',function () { return view('calendar');});

    Route::resource('events', 'EventsController',['only' => ['index', 'store']]);
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

And when I take out `{{ Form::open(['route' => 'events.store', 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form']) }` the page loads fine again ,but I will need that line of code in the future

php artisan route list
[image]

Comment: is it a nested route?

Comment: What do you see when running `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @JeffPuckett I just put up screenshot of what I got from `php artisan route:list` in the question

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I'm not sure I was just following a tutorial

Comment: you can see that it's a nested route, so the route name is fully `user.events.store`

Comment: I just Fixed it!

Comment: Yes ,you were right ,I have never had experience with that before ,didn't realize I made such a simple mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'user.events.store', 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form']) }}
```

According to your route:list you should have `user.events.store` in your from route